# Combining two columns in R

Tags: r, mapreduce

I have two columns in R:

```
Origin    Dest  
ALB       ATL  
ALB       LAG  
ALB       LAX
```

I need them to look like this (in one column):

```
Origin-Dest  
ALB-ATL  
ALB-LAG  
ALB-LAX
```

Does anyone know how to combine two lines without getting too complicated?
This is the code I have so far:

```
air <- read.table(delta, header=T, sep=",")  
aircolSQL <- sqldf("select Origin, Dest, ActualElapsedTime from air")  
airsortSQL <- sqldf("select * from aircolSQL order by Origin asc, Dest")  
airsortSQL$ActualTimeHours = round((airsortSQL$ActualElapsedTime/60),1)  
airsortSQL$ActualElapsedTime <-  NULL
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `airsortSQL$Origin_Dest <- with(airsortSQL,paste0(Origin,"-",Dest))`. I don't think hyphens are allowed in column names.

Comment: Column names with operator characters are allowed but are kind of a PITA because access requires that they be quoted.

Comment: @nrussell, you should convert your comment into answer, the base R solution is more than enough to handle the case.  : )

Comment: @KFB thank you, feel free to add it I'll be away from my computer for a while.

Answer (score 3):

If `df` is your data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(Origin = rep('ALB', 3), Dest = c('ATL', 'LAG', 'LAX'))

library(tidyr)
unite_(df, '`Origin-Dest`', c('Origin', 'Dest'), sep = "-")

  `Origin-Dest`
1       ALB-ATL
2       ALB-LAG
3       ALB-LAX
```

Answer (score 3):

In SQLite `||` is used for string concatenation:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select Origin || '-' || Dest OD from air")
```

giving:

```
       OD
1 ALB-ATL
2 ALB-LAG
3 ALB-LAX
```

**data** We used this as `air`:

```
air <- structure(list(Origin = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "ALB", 
class = "factor"), Dest = structure(1:3, .Label = c("ATL", "LAG", "LAX"), 
class = "factor")), .Names = c("Origin", "Dest"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

I often use paste:

```
DataFrame$OriginDest<- paste(DataFrame$Origin,DataFrame$Dest, sep = '-')
```

I find it the least hassle approach.